# sql simple join using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to run a simple join query using sqoop. Below is the query.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --username    root -P --query 'select d.department_name,c.category_name from departments d join categories c on d.department_id = c.category_department_id group by d.department_name,c.category_name where $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /sqoop26 -m 1
```

But i encountered with the below error.

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where  (1 = 0)' at line 1
```

The same join query is running fine in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an error in your sql sintax. Use your whereconditions before the group by like this

```
select d.department_name,c.category_name from departments d join categories c on d.department_id = c.category_department_id where $CONDITIONS group by d.department_name,c.category_name
```

or

```
select * from (
select d.department_name,c.category_name from departments d join categories  c on d.department_id = c.category_department_id  
group by d.department_name,c.category_name 
) t where $CONDITIONS
```

Comment: oh man!! i have not thought about the $CONDITIONS is a part of where clause and placed as a last option.... Thanks!!!!